# Read/Write Data from/to File in Uppaal (For Data Log)

Tags: file, io, formal-verification, uppaal

How to write some data into a file as a log or some statistics in Uppaal?
Is there any `fprintf` function or some `FILE*` such as we have in `C` or not? The same question for reading from the file too.

Answer (score 0):

There are no native input-output functions inside Uppaal model. For debugging, you can use `assert` function to stop verification when condition does not hold.

Since version 4.1.4 Uppaal has integrated Statistical Model Checking queries for estimating the performance of the modeled processes (see Uppaal SMC Tutorial). The gathered data can be exported as CSV. There is also `verifyta` command line interface included in the distribution.

Uppaal Stratego can load user-defined functions from external dynamically linked library (DLL) into model (where in principal one is free to do anything), but it requires technical skills to prepare such a library, there are no checks and thus is not friendly for rapid prototyping. This option is mostly for faster execution of very complicated code.